# Changing an Image within a Cell with UIGestureRecognizer attached to UIImageView - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I've been wrestling for hours with the following problem: I have an image in each of my cells of a UITableView which I'd like to toggle when tapped. Currently, in the function where I establish the cells,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

I have the following code which attaches the UIGestureRecognizer to the image in each cell:

```
cell.imageView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.imageView!.tag = indexPath.row
var tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedImage:")
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.imageView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
```

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to change that cell's image in:

```
func TappedImage(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

It seems that I am able to change the background for the image, or set it to hidden, for example, but not actually change it. Maybe this is a question of accessing the cell? I've been trying to figure out how I would define it in this function from the imageView tag, but I also have sections, which I think may make the tag less relevant (as I would need to reference both section and row). I have the toggle function written which passes in a cell which I could easily call from this function if I can access the exact cell. Any advice or sample code is much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Thank you

Comment: How did you implement `TappedImage` function ?

Comment: '    func TappedCheckbox(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //var imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view!
        //var cell : UITableViewCell! = view.superview!
        ^this gave an error
        //println(sender.view!.tag)
        println(sender.view!.tag)
   ^this gives row number
        //sender.view!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        //sender.view!.hidden = true
   ^this works but not what I want
        //change chore to done or not done
    }'

Comment: Sorry I know it's messy - new here. Basically I tried to get the cell so I could change the image that way, but what I tried gave an error. I could change the background and hidden status with the sender, but not the image itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: ^I changed it to TappedCheckbox but obviously that shouldn't matter

Comment: What is the error you are getting when used : `imageView.image = yourImage`

Comment: When I do this: var imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view! --> I get UIView is not convertible to UIImageView. And in the next line: var cell : UITableViewCell! = view.superview! --> I get UIView is not convertible to UITableViewCell. I've also tried var imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view! and get UITapGestureRecognizer is not convertible to UIImageView. Any thoughts? Without these errors I think imageView.image = yourImage would work

Comment: Try this `var imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view! as UIImageView`

Comment: Didn't quite work but it seems like we're getting somewhere so thank you! I tried: I tried this just as a test with no success:

        var imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view! as UIImageView
        var image : UIImage! = imageView.image!
        image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")

Any thoughts why?

Comment: You need to set it to your imageview. Like `imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")`

Comment: That's fantastic thank you! You've been such a great help just one more question - if I want to be able to access that specific cell so that I can change its data (I am using both sections and rows, so tagging will only give a row) how do I go about that? Also feel free to add an official answer and I'll give you the checkmark!